# simple random walk and supremum

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, supremum-and-infimum

Let $S_n$ be a simple random walk: $S_0 = 0, S_n = U_1 + \ldots + U_n$, where
$U_i$ are iid such that $0 < P(U_1 = 1) = p < 1$, $P(U_1 = −1) = 1 − p = q$.

Suppose $F_0 = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ and $F_n = \sigma(U_1, \ldots, U_n)$.

Let $Z_n = (q/p)^{S_n}$.

(a) Show that $Z_n$ is a positive martingale.

(b) Let $k \in \mathbb{N} ∪ \{0\}$. Show that
$$P(\sup_{n\geq0} S_n \geq k) \leq (p/q)^k$$

and that, if $q > p$, $$\mathbb{E}(\sup_{n\geq0} S_n) \leq p/q − p.$$

I managed to solve part a. Please help me with part b

Comment: What did you try for part (b)

Comment: hi I'm just confused about where to start with that

Comment: I tried to improve the layout by using Tex, but I hope I didn't accidentally change the meaning of some expression, please check.

Comment: it is correct thank you